# Uninstall Docker when installed via curl

Tags: debian, docker

I have installed docker un my debian 7 server using the following command :

```
sudo curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
```

I would now like to remove docker, how on earth do I uninstall it ?

Comment: And that, children, is why you don't install software this way on a server. Try https://docs.docker.com/installation/debian/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For older versions of docker installed via curl

```
sudo curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
```

You can remove docker with

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove docker #Removes docker and dependencies
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker #Removes all data
```

Edit: 05/2018:
For newer versions according to online [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/debian/#uninstall-docker-ce)

```
$ sudo apt-get purge docker-ce
```

To remove images, containers, volumes, or customized configuration files on your host that are not automatically removed

```
$ sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker
```

Comment: It doesnt make it clear if the method works with the curl method. I end up reading the script :P

Comment: This didn't work for me. The documentation now says run `sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker-ce docker.io`

Comment: Ive updated the answer to cover newer versions of docker.

Answer (score 2):

In my case (debian|raspbian|bullseye) I did the following to remove docker installed via the official `get-docker.sh` script:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list    
sudo rm /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg 
sudo apt remove docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-compose-plugin docker-ce-rootless-extras docker-buildx-plugin
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker
sudo apt autoremove
```

Answer (score 0):

```
apt remove "--purge docker*"
rm -rf /var/lib/docker
apt autoremove
```

Comment: Docket was not installed with apt.

Comment: On the contrary, the `get.docker.com` script does, indeed, use `apt` to install the `docker` packages.